# How to count the motherboard slots and get the motherboard serial number through java?

Tags: java, sigar

How to count the motherboard slots and get the motherboard serial number through java? Im using Sigar Java API for getting all other informations. But i don't know how to get the mentioned informations.

Comment: Why not try serverfault, stackoverflow might not be the correct forum. On the other hand, I have an hunch that the answer has to do with <a href src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_abstraction_layer"></a>. You may have more success if you ask for the existence of any system call that can return this information.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sigar does not provide such information yet. But we can gather information in another way. I don't know about how to get MotherBoard slots but MotherBoard serial number can be get very easily using VBS (Window Script).

Just write down the below script in a file with extension .vbs

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
("Select * from Win32_BaseBoard") 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber 
    exit for  ' do the first cpu only!
```

Invoke these file using Runtime class as,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + "my.vbs");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line;
String result = "";
  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
     result += line;
  }
  input.close();
System.out.println(result);
```

Note: This way will work only on Window machines because it's platform depended code for Windows OS only.